# Get value in 2nd li tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tags, element

What I need to get value "Bra" inside the second li, i didn't use clas category64 because the class change every page.

```
    <div class="breadcrumbs">
    <ul>
        <li class="home"><li>
        <li class="category63">
            <a href="http://asdasd.com/xyz/ title">Panty</a>
            <span>/ </span>
        </li>
        <li class="category93">
            <a href="http://asdasd.com/xyz" title=>Pierre Cardin</a>
            <span>/ </span>
                    </li>
        <li class="category64">
            <strong>Bra</strong>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have problem to get the value, 
if i get the value on 2nd li , why the output "Pierre Cardin/", the output have "/", how to not include the "/" ?

Comment: try to this $('.breadcrumbs > li:nth-of-type(2) strong').text();

Comment: Your <ul> element have a class ? You can use Jquery ?

Comment: i'm sorry, i will implement this with javascript. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector, it matches the element for given index

```js
var text = document.querySelector('.breadcrumbs li:nth-child(2)').innerText;
alert(text);
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <ul>
    <li class="category63">
      <a href="http://asdasd.com/xyz/ title">Panty</a>
      <span>/ </span>
    </li>
    <li class="category64">
      <strong>Bra</strong>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: He must use only JS...

Comment: sorry, i implement this with javascript.

Comment: i change the code because there is isue, can you correct your answer? @RayonDabre

Comment: @RayonDabre i implement the code, but the output is undefined. :(

Comment: Click on the __Run Code Snippet__ and check...

Comment: i already to implement the code and it work. but the output string is upper case "BRA & PANTY", how i can change value on normal?

Comment: Value being alerted is in the `Normal case`..As it is in the markup..

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll(".breadcrumbs li")[1].innerText;
alert(a);
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/juvexexuna/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: i'm sorry,i change the code beacuse the code is incorrect. @yangguang

Comment: i change the code because there is issue, can you correct your answer?

Comment: @StevenAndrian, the selector ".breadcrumbs li" will find all li elements in class "breadcrumbs", so the code is still ok, after you add the ul tag. But, in you demo code, there missing a "</li>" tag.

Comment: i implement the code, but the output is undefined. :( but if i change to innerHTML,  the output is <a href="http://asdasd.com/xyz/ title">Panty</a>
            <span>/ </span>

Comment: @StevenAndrian, can you provide your issue demo? jsfiddle or jsbin.

Comment: i already fix the code

Answer (score 0):

Used to this code in jquery

`var  code = $('.breadcrumbs > li:nth-of-type(2) strong').text(); alert(code);`

Comment: sorry, i implement this with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You have several option:

First: Attach an id to the `<strong>` tag

```
<strong id="myId">Bra</strong>
```

and get the value with:

```
 var text = document.getelementById('myId').innerHTML;
```

Second: Use getElementsByTagName() to get it as:

```
var text = document.getelementByTagName('li')[1].innerHTML;
```

But personally I do not recommend it, since the value of the li could vary if you add more li tags to the DOM tree above the one you want to get.

It could be possible add the id attribute to the li instead than to the strong tag, but then you will nned to get the firstchild before get the innerHTML as:

```
var text = document.getelementById('myId').firstChild.innerHTML;
```